# iOS ActivityView Twitter Incorrectly changes URL Length

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

On iOS 6 and iOS 7, if I share the text:

```
www.google.com is such a cool website, I really enjoy going to it. You should check out the other one too! www.facebook.com
```

It says the text is too long by -15 characters. However, if I share the same text on Twitter.com or from OS X, I am fine (by 3 characters).

I am using a `UIActivityViewController` to share via `UIActivityTypePostToTwitter`. Just sending it to the `UIActivityViewController` as a NSString.

It appears as though the URL shortening is completely broken on iOS. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this today - it looks like if you type out a 109 character tweet and then add a URL of any length, then the post fills up and you have 0 characters left. So it looks like instead of [URLs being 22 characters long as documented on Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/78124-how-to-shorten-links-urls), on iOS they are 31 characters long.

I confirmed this with a URL that is 27 characters long and then the rest of the tweet was 113 characters. This should have been the exact limit of 140 characters, but instead the share sheet (aka UIActivityViewController) said it was over the limit by 4 characters.

I did the math for your example and found that it is 123 characters, but subtracting out 14 for www.google.com, 16 for www.facebook.com, then adding in 31 each URL, you get 155 characters, which is where you get the -15 characters in your question.

tldr: Any URL shared to Twitter via UIActivityViewController is counted as 31 characters.

Comment: BUT WHYYYYYYYYYY, and is there any way around this? That's not the length of the URL shortener it makes.

Comment: I wish I knew. I guess we'll have to file Radars with Apple and hope they fix it.